# What is the physical meaning of the s-space?

Tags: signal-analysis

In my audio processing lecture, the term `s-space` came up.

My instructor basically told us that it's a space where we perform calculations that couldn't be performed otherwise in the time space. Although he also mentioned that the s-space doesn't have a physical meaning or at least none that he is aware of, I'm curious if it has one. How exactly one can describe the s-space physically?

Also do you have a broader explanation for the s-space with some easy to grasp examples?

Comment: I assume you mean the [Laplace domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform). In short, Laplace transforms are often used to solve certain types of differential equations. Differential equations show up in the context of continuous-time linear time-invariant systems, hence the connection. When it's usable, differential equations in the time domain map to polynomial equations in the Laplace domain, which can often make analysis easier.

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180021/what-is-the-laplace-transform-and-how-is-it-performed-detailed-explanation/1180206#1180206) on math.SE gives a simple explanation of the Laplace transform. Maybe it helps.